# Understanding relative Eilenberg-Zilber Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, modules, functors

In [Tom Dieck](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/diecktop.pdf) p.$9.7.2$ there is a proof of a the relative version of the [Eilenberg-Zilber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Zilber_theorem) Theorem which I'm going to attach here

[image]

What I don't get here is how $S_\bullet((X,A)\times (Y,B))$ is defined since I'd like to prove that if $$A \times Y \cup X \times B = \text{int}(A \times Y) \cup \text{int}(X \times B)$$

Then we have an isomorphism (using $9.7.2$) between the homologies of $S_\bullet(X,A) \otimes S(Y,B)$ and $S_\bullet((X,A)\times (Y,B))$ but I'm unable to do it since I don't recognize the spaces involved.

Maybe this isomorphism is not crucial, but I think it could be useful further on when cup and cap product are involed.

Comment: Zilber, not Zielber...

Comment: @paulgarrett Do you know the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've not thought about this for a while, and would not trust myself to pretend to say anything... apart from knowing the spelling. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett thanks anyway and thanks for the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on context, we have already defined
$$S(X,A) = \frac{S(X)}{S(A)}$$
and
$$(X,A) \times (Y,B) = (X\times Y, X\times B \cup A\times Y).$$
Altogether, we have
$$S((X,A) \times (Y,B)) = \frac{S(X \times Y)}{S(X \times B \cup A \times Y)}$$

Comment: Thought so, do you see how to prove that there's an isomorphism based knowing that $H_n(S(A\times Y)+S(X\times B)) \simeq H_n(A \times Y \cup X \times B)?$

Comment: One can obtain the desired isomorphism from the one you provide by comparing long exact sequences (LES) in homology. In particular, I would compare the LES for $S(X\times B \cup A\times Y) \subseteq S(X \times Y)$ with the LES for $S(X\times B) + S(A\times Y) \subseteq S(X \times Y)$.

Comment: What's the map from $S((X,A)\times (Y\times B))$ to $S(X\times Y)/(S(X\times B)+S(A\times Y))$ that makes the square commute in order to pass the SES in homology?

Comment: I don't know of a map going that way, but there is a map going in the other direction.

Comment: Is the projection that goes in the other direction?