# Relative cap product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, tensor-products, functors

I'd like to understand relative cap product based on my notes. We want a map $$H^i(X,A) \otimes H_n(X,A \cup B) \longmapsto H_{n-i}(X,B)$$

In order to understand the construction, we want to give a map $C_\bullet(X,A \cup B) \overset{\tilde{\Delta}}{\longmapsto} C_\bullet(X,A) \otimes C_\bullet(X,B)$. But what's this map?

In fact, we can consider $0 \longmapsto C_\bullet(A) \longmapsto C_\bullet(X) \longmapsto C_\bullet(X,A) \longmapsto 0$ and tensor with $C_\bullet(X,B)$ to get

$$0 \longmapsto C_\bullet(A) \otimes C_\bullet(X,B) \longmapsto C_\bullet(X)\otimes C(X,B) \longmapsto C_\bullet(X,A) \otimes C_\bullet(X,B) \longmapsto 0$$

Now consider the following commutative diagram

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 C_\bullet(A) & \to & C_\bullet(X,B) & \to & C_\bullet(X,A \cup B) & \to & 0 \\\
\downarrow{\Delta} & & \downarrow{\Delta} & & \downarrow{\Delta} \\\
 C_\bullet(A \times (X,B)) &  & C_\bullet(A \times(X,B)) &  & C_\bullet((X,A)\times (X,B)) \\\ \downarrow{EZ} & & \downarrow{EZ} & & \downarrow{EZ} \\\ 0  \to C_\bullet(A) \otimes C_\bullet(X,B) &\to & C_\bullet(X)\otimes C(X,B) & \to & C_\bullet(X,A) \otimes C_\bullet(X,B) & \to 0
\end{array}$$

I have the following questions:

$0$. Why having the map $C_\bullet(X,A \cup B) \overset{\tilde{\Delta}}{\longmapsto} C_\bullet(X,A) \otimes C_\bullet(X,B)$ we end up with the cap product $H^i(X,A) \otimes H_n(X,A \cup B) \longmapsto H_{n-i}(X,B)$ ?

$1$. The sequence on the first line how is it build? I think the map $C_\bullet(X,B) \longmapsto C_\bullet(X,A \cup B)$ is surjective, is this enough in order to get the sequence?

$2$. Why the diagram is commutative and how this could help to prove $0$?

$3$. The $EZ$ in the diagram, seem the relative Eilenberg Zielber maps (reference [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4233787/understanding-relative-eilenberg-zilber-theorem)).

If so, are $C_\bullet((X,A) \times (Y,B)) = C_\bullet(X \times Y) / (C_\bullet(A \times Y)+ C\bullet(X\times B))$ and $C_\bullet(A \times (X,B))$ defined as the previous with $A = (A,\varnothing)$?

$4$. Are the vertical $\Delta$s in reality the diagonal map composed with a projection?

Any help or reference would be appreciated.